# Is delocalisation of non-bonding electrons into the benzene ring possible in case of conjugate base of benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance

If we take a look at conjugate base of benzoic acid it is as given below:

[image]

Now my question is:

Is delocalisation of non bonding electrons(in the carboxylate part) into the benzene ring possible?

Critical Comment:I think that it won't be possible because we would end up having negative charge on both the oxygen which should make it less stable.

Reference supporting my claim:

Although the reason I gave may or may not be the actual,i don't know, but the reference also claims the same thing i.e delocalisation of non bonding electrons doesn't occur.

Link: https://www.asu.edu/courses/chm233/notes/acids/acids2017.html

scroll down and check this:
Factors controlling acidity and under that check 'substituent effects for some aromatic carboxylic acids'

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19843/why-cant-the-conjugate-base-of-benzoic-acid-be-stabilized-by-conjugation-with-t

Answer (score -1):

Well definitely not. The simplest answer would be that if you tried to do it, you would get a really absurd Resonance structure. What would actually occur is -
The non bonding electrons would delocalise only between the oxygen atoms and the benzene ring would have its own separate electron delocalisation(as in a normal benzene ring)which would have nothing to do with the former. This would be favored because-

1.The non bonding electron would be with only oxygen(which is more electronegative and hence gives better stabilizing effect to the resonance hybrid).

2. It gives rise to equivalent resonance structures which greatly enhance stability

Comment: Is any form of delocalisation possible where the benzene ring participates in resonance with carboxylate ion? If no such thing is possible then ortho effect would make no sense because if no resonance occurs in the first place between the ring and the carboxylate ion then we cant use the concept of steric inhibition of resonance

Comment: I knew this point would come up. Ortho effect is an experimental observation which we try to explain via theoretical Organic Chemistry. Hence there is more than 1 explanation to the problem, of which the conjugate base explanation is a bit weird(as said by my teacher and not justified). There's another one involving resonance in the acid itself which also involves SIR which seems more valid. Check it out if you want to. And my answer is pretty much valid according to the explanation I am referring to.

Comment: Isn't Steric inhibition of Resonance(SIR) effect similar to that of ortho effect.It's just that if SIR occurs in benzoic acid then it is Ortho effect right?...And moreover you provided no answer to my question about the existence of any other resonance structure involving benzene ring.It would be great if you explain the question in my previous comment as it would clear a lot of doubts for me.

Comment: This is wrong. Of course there is conjugation between the carboxyl group and the aromatic ring, they are after all in plane and belong to the same pi system. Just because you cannot draw a valid Lewis structure for this resonance contributor, it doesn't mean that the contribution does not exist.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン if there is conjugation what is it? Could you please provide the resonance structures

Comment: Yes I was wrong to not include the conjugated form as a contributing Lewis Structure because for the Reso Hybrid every possible structure has to be considered(irrespective of their feasibility).But with respect to the resonance hybrid its contribution would be very little and the hybrid would greatly resemble what I wrote in my main answer.To sum up what I believe is right according to my knowledge-The conjugated form would be a contributing Resonance structure albeit of limited contribution to the hybrid.Also ortho effect is also found in Aromatic amines(but there it reduces there basicity)

Comment: Your knowledge is wrong. Your answer is wrong. You interpret a Lewis structure as a literal resonance contributor, and you assume that just because you cannot fathom a Lewis structure for that kind of conjugation, the conjugation does not exist. Also it is impossible to judge from a Lewis structure alone whether it has little or large contribution to the bonding situation.

Comment: Well I guess I have to get back to studying again.Thanks for letting me know.